# Difference between `exit;` and `exit $?;`

Tags: bash, shell-script, exit, exit-status

Is there any difference between these two commands:

```
   exec "$(dirname "$0")/suman-shell";
   exit $?;
```

and

```
   exec "$(dirname "$0")/suman-shell";
   exit;
```

is the `$?` redundant in the first case?

Comment: So are the semicolons

Comment: semicolons are beautiful and signal intent :) plus if I wanted I could do `x; exit;` on the same line, yolo

Comment: Well, it could be argued `$?` do signal intent much more than the semicolons. Bash isn't C.

Comment: yeah but could you put commands on the same line tho

Comment: I use sc's in bash to put things on the same line and to signal intent. sometimes I write code without sc's, then go through it again later and add sc's after I determine that each line is correct. it's proof that everything works, you don't even need to test your code after that :) lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several flaws in your script:

```
exec "$(dirname "$0")/suman-shell";
exit $?;
```

- The first one is the ending semicolons are redundant. They are harmless but serve no purpose. An end of line is already a separator, semicolons are used as a separator between multiple commands on a single line. Their presence here slightly worsen the code readability.
- The second one is `exit` by default returns the exit status of the previous command, so stating `$?` is redundant, albeit signalling the intent.
- The third one is `exec` never returns under normal circumstances<sup>1</sup>, so the `exit` call is not reached in the first place and is also redundant.

<sup>1</sup> The only cases where `exec` returns is an empty argument, a broken redirection or the `execfail`bash option set (which is not the default setting). The first and second ones do not apply here, and there is no evidence the third one does.

Comment: true with regard to the exec call, so I should either get rid of exec or exit..

Comment: ixnay on the semicolon critique tho, there is nothing more beautiful than a properly placed semicolon, sometimes I put two or three just to look at them `;;;`

Comment: Hmm, as beautiful as they might be, two or three semicolons in a row make nothing better than a syntax error as far as `bash` is concerned...

Answer (score 8):

From `help exit`:

> Exits the shell with a status of N.  If N is omitted, the exit status is that of the last command executed.

So yes, it is completely redundant.

Comment: Or one could note that the difference in question occurs in a line of script that normally will never be reached, given the `exec`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The `exit` present in the script isn't reached in the first place. `exec` failing will directly exit the script bypassing any line that would follow.

Answer (score 6):

Strictly speaking, there's a difference between `exit` and `exit $?` when `$IFS` contains digits when [you forget to quote that `$?` and thus are invoking the split+glob operator](/q/171346):

```
$ bash -c 'IFS=123; false; exit $?'; echo "$?"
bash: line 0: exit: : numeric argument required
2
$ bash -c 'IFS=123; false; exit'; echo "$?"
1
$ bash -c 'IFS=123; false; exit "$?"'; echo "$?"
1
$ bash -c "exit ''"
bash: line 0: exit: : numeric argument required
```

In the first case, because the `$?` is unquoted, it's subject to word splitting. With `$IFS` containing `1`, the content of `$?` (`1`) is split into one empty argument in `bash`, so it's as if you had called `exit ''`.