# Does running "exec echo some; echo test" in bash never print "some test"?

Tags: shell, exec

Does running `exec echo "some "; echo "test"` in bash never print "some test"?

I would seek confirmation to this question, as I am writing a small shell script and I would like it to not contiue anything after the `exec` command has been called.

I think that I would not need to worry, as my understanding, after consulting:

- `man 3 exec`
- `man 1p exec`

The shell scripts, when executed by the shell will make

1. the shell execute the program `exec`, which
2. uses the `exec***` family system calls that replace the shell/bash that which has been executing the script, by this *impeding* further actions of the shell (which was "replaced")

As laid out before, main goal of this question is to seek confirmation for my reasoning as to prevent that anything in the script occuring after the exec (such as `echo test`) would be executed.

I would appreciate a general answer (POSIX), as far as possible, but just in case of particularities I am most interested in GNU/Linux and GNU/Bash

Comment: This came up recently in answers to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403349/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` does always finish the script **if** it executes a command and does so successfully (not related to the command's exit code but to starting it).

`exec` can be run without a command in a very useful way: To permanently redirect file descriptors:

```
exec 3>/path/to/file
```

If the command cannot be started then the shell behaviour depends on the configuration. `bash` exits by default.

It may be best for you to use a function instead:

```
safe_exec () {
    cmd="$1"
    if test -z "$cmd" || ! test -f "$cmd" || ! test -x "$cmd"; then
        exit 1
    else
        exec "$@"
    fi
}

safe_exec echo "some "; echo "test"
```

Comment: I had not considered the case of `exec` failing to "execute" the command/program (e.g. for the it not being in path or else). I also appreciated the answer with the safe_exec(), which I have to confirm yet to be without bashisms, as else bash -as mentioned by you exits on fail by default. thank you

Comment: @humanityANDpeace `safe_exec` would have to be modified for finding commands in PATH.

Comment: `safe_exec` seems more complicated than necessary: wouldn't `exec "$@"; exit 1` work just as well? (Actually, better, since it avoids the problem of commands in PATH not being found.)

Comment: Your `safe_exec` doesn't work as written as it doesn't look up the path of the executable before testing for -z/-f/-x... Even if it did, note that contrary to `exec`, it could cause an EXIT trap to be executed.

Comment: The case where `bash` fails to `execve` the command is a bit more complicated than indicated in this answer. After the failure it first does a bunch of things to try and work around the failing `execve` in an attempt to deal with badly formatted scripts. Secondly whether it exits or continues by default depends on whether it is an interactive shell (at least on Ubuntu 14.04 it does).

Answer (score 7):

Right, if `exec` succeeds, it replaces the current shell, so the following commands are not, err.. executed.

However, [at least in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-exec), the shell also exits if the `exec` *fails*:

> `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`
>
> If *command* is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process. [...]  If *command* cannot be executed for some reason, a non-interactive shell exits, unless the `execfail` shell option is enabled. In that case, it returns failure.

So even something like `bash -c 'exec /bin/nosuchfile; echo foo'` will just print an error message about the missing program file. To handle the error in the script, you'd need something like

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s execfail
exec /someprogram
echo whoops, it failed
```

But, you still get the error message from `exec`. If you put a redirection on the `exec`, *it stays in effect* if the script continues after the `exec` failed.

Comment: That's also a POSIX requirement. `exec` being a _special builtin_ its failure (at least when non-interactive) is required to be fatal.

Answer (score 5):

The `exec` builtin (with a command argument¹) replaces the shell process². No subsequent code in the shell process is executed.

Thus the only way `exec echo "some "; echo "test"` would print `some text` is if there was an executable command called `echo` in the PATH, and this executable printed `some text` rather than `some`. It cannot happen under normal circumstances where the `echo` executable behaves as one would expect from a command called `echo`.

If there is no executable file called `echo` in the PATH or executing it fails, then `exec` will display an error message and exit the shell. Even in that case, `echo "test"` is not executed.

¹  <sub>`exec` without a command argument is a different beast. It doesn't replace the shell process, it just applies redirections.</sub> 
²  <sub>In a subshell, only the subshell is affected, the parent shell keeps running normally.</sub>